# Do I need to manually uninstall/reinstall drivers if I replace my GPU?

Tags: gpu, gpu-driver

I'm going to replace my nvidia GTX 1080 with a nvidia GT 730. Can I just replace it and let Ubuntu take care of the drivers or will I need to manually do something?

Thanks

Comment: *theoretically* you don't need to do anything.

Comment: That some downgrade but it's likely they can use the same driver version.

Answer (score 1):

If you talking about the nouveau drivers, no, you do not need to do anything.

If you are talking about the Nvidia proprietary dirver then *theoretically* you don't need to do anything, but probably the safest thing to do is to revert to the nouveau driver before replacing it and then reinstall the proprietary ones.